# $\pi^{b}$ transcendental?

Tags: abstract-algebra, self-learning

I asked a similar question in a different thread but that one got answered and I thought this would be the natural extension.

Is $\pi^{b}$ transcendental for any algebraic $b$? Is this a known result? If this is too broad maybe something like $\pi^{\sqrt{2}}$. I feel like if $\pi^{2}$ is transcendental and if there is any justice in the world so should $\pi^{\sqrt{2}}$.

Thanks.

Comment: You might wanna require $b\neq 0$, though.

Comment: The square of Pi is certainly trascendental. Just write down what it would mean if it were algebraic!

Comment: For the rest, see http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem (and the links there) for an example of what is known.

Answer (score 1):

According to Wikipedia, most sums, products, powers, etc., of $\pi$ have unknown status; in particular, it isn't known whether $\pi^{\sqrt{2}}$ is transcendental.  However, your suggestion that this should follow from the transcendental nature of $\pi^2$ (together with the existence of justice in the world) is certainly false.  Consider $x=2^{\sqrt{2}/2}$.  It provides a counterexample, in that $x^2=2^{\sqrt{2}}$ is transcendental (the [Gelfond-Schneider constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_constant)), while $x^{\sqrt{2}}=2$ ([two](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2_%28number%29)) is not.